# How download file from EC2 by python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a EC2 instance, and I would programmatically download a file by python script. I can acess by FTP, and tried use ftplib to download, but i have a timeout error.

```py
#I Try this command
import os
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(host=ip)
ftp.login(user=login,passwd=passw)
ftp.dir()
# but have timeout error
```

Comment: Check your security group first. Then your network ACL. Then your network firewall. Port 21 has to be whitelisted on all of these.

Comment: It's OK! The ftp access work well if I access by FIleZilla or by browser, but when I access by python code have timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
$ ssh -i KeyPair.pem ubuntu@ec2-22-345-22-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com

# Username can be ubuntu or ec2-user, depending upon your instance type
```

You can use CLI itself or develop a `import os` Python script containing the following syntaxes to copy all files from an EC2 folder to local drive:

```
$ chmod 400 ~/anaconda3/KeyPair.pem

$ scp -r -i KeyPair.pem ubuntu@ec2-22-345-22-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com:anaconda3/Data/. D:/Data
```